# Full type name followed by index, what does it mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, types

I am trying to understand the logging output of `dotnet run` for an ASP.NET Core project. There are many places showing a full type name followed by what appears to be the indexer syntax.

This [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname?view=netframework-4.8) explains how array types are represented, but in that case there is no index.

`Console.WriteLine(new string[100]);` shows:
`System.String[]`

This is an actual `dotnet run` output:
`info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[58]`

How to interpret the previous text? What is 58?

Is it a general C# string representation? What code construct would output something like that?

Comment: It's a log message, which is a string (and not C# code, so I removed the [tag:syntax] tag).  There may be no connection between the type and the number.  You can output something like that with `Console.WriteLine($"{x.GetType().Name}[{DateTime.Now.Minute}]")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example provided, there are three components:

1. `info`, which is the [log level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-level).
2. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager`, which is the [log category](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-category).
3. `58`, which is the [log event ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-event-id).

ASP.NET Core uses `ILogger` and `ILogger<T>` for logging, using calls such as:

```
logger.LogInformation(...);
```

The example log message you've shown is from a console provider, which has its own rules about how to format the message. By default, this starts with a header line of `level: category[eventID]`, as I've shown.

As a crude example, you might imagine the following code being used to generate the final message:

```
var logLevel = "info";
var logCategory = "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager";
var logEventId = 58;

Console.Writeline($"{logLevel}: {logCategory}[{logEventId}]");
```